# Sprint Boot Application Shutdown

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot Application which listens to JCAPS. The Connection is Durable.
When I shutdown the Application using

```
Curl -X POST ip:port//shutdown
```

Application is not shutting down completely. I can see the PID when I grep the processes. So I tried to kill using

```
Kill -15 PID
```

or

```
Kill -SIGTERM PID
```

The PID is gone, but the subscription to JCAPS topic is still Active. Hence, When I restart the Application, I am unable to connect to the same Topic using the same subscriber name.

Please help on How to properly shutdown the spring boot application.

Comment: use `kill -9 pid`

Comment: I have tried kill -9 pid which is killing the process abruptly which is also not making the Subscriber inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Set following property in application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Then start spring-boot app

You want to shutdown app run following curl command

**curl -X POST localhost:port/actuator/shutdown**

Reference : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown